# MobileFirst 7.0.0 application on Windows Phone 8.1 error from Weinre

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst, weinre

The MobileFirst application that we've developed works on iOS, Android. The Windows Phone 8.1 port is showing following error when displaying console messages on weinre console:

```
Error in Error callbackId: WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin1600160345 : TypeError: Unable to get property 'WL-Authentication-Success' of undefined or null reference
Uncaught Exception: Unable to get property 'WL-Authentication-Success' of undefined or null reference at (compiled_code):303
```

What could be the reason why this error comes? I have Security Test:Default and App Authenticity Configuration:None.

What can be the Reason of this error?

Comment: That's a very... "shot in the dark" type of question. The error is not revealing enough in itself, so it must be debugged. If you are able to re-create this in a simple application that uses weinre and a basic authentication flow - update your question with the steps and a sample project, otherwise - unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a new fresh application all worked fine.
The investigation with console logs showed that the error came from WL.Client.connect() call.
Anyway I deleted windowsphone8 enviroment, re-created and worked now it works. Also the line `connectOnStartup: false,` was commended I've reenabled but I don't think this was the problem.